# current_page? method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

There is a way to insert all the pages of a controller in the current_page?() method?

```
<%if (!current_page?(:controller=>'users'))%>
    ...
<%end>
```

If I don't insert the :action attribute don't work!

I must to insert the attribute :action if i want to make a control for a specific action.

I would to consider all of the pages of the controller named users.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `current_page`, you can check the controller name directly:

```
<% if controller.controller_name != "users" %>
...
<% end %>
```

Comment: `controller_name` is enough and recommended for this purpose.

Comment: @GiacomoDelfini: Please accept one of the answers — whichever worked best for you.

Answer (score 0):

`params[:controller] != 'users'`

Comment: `controller_name` is recommended for this purpose. See section 3.3: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#routing-parameters

Comment: Nope, it isn't. The things are opposite. `controller_name` caches its result on first invocation (which happens before page rendering), so it just returns its instance variable on next calls. Calling `params[:controller]` takes some time to lookup.